# Как добавить UNIX дату в БД?

Tags: python

Есть для спрашенных новостей БД. Стояла задача реализовать добавление в БД в UNIX формате  дату появившейся новости в столбец `nd_date` и дату добавленной новости в саму БД в столбец `s_date`.Чтобы было так как на примере:
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
Я реализовал добавление в БД столбца `nd_date`.Код:

```
# < Создаю обьект гуся.
            g = Goose()
            # < С помощью гуся получаю дату.
            goose_date = g.extract(url=item_link).publish_date
            # < Условие если гусь нашел дату.
            if goose_date is not None:
                # < Конвертирую дату.
                date_parsed = dateparser.parse(goose_date)
                not_date = date_parsed.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                # < Конвертированную дату  конвертирую в формат UNIX.
                nd_date = int(time.mktime( time.strptime(not_date, '%Y-%m-%d')))
                # Дальше идет insert в БД.
```

Теперь я не могу понять как реализовать дату добавленной новости в саму БД в столбец `s_date`.

Comment: Непонятно, в чём суть вопроса. Вы не умеете отправлять sql-запросы из python-кода или в чём проблема?

Comment: Для s_date Можно использовать тип поля current_timestamp, и никаких дополнительных insert-ов не надо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал это так:

```
# < Получаем дату в формате UNIX.
    def get_s_date(self):
        s_date = time.time()
        return s_date
```

Comment: Как это отвечает на ваш вопрос?

Comment: Ну мой вопрос заключался в том что я не понимал как реализовать запись `s_date`.

Comment: Запись в БД? В ответе только получение текущего времени.

Comment: Ну чтобы что-то записать в бд,надо же что-то иметь.Ну собственно вот,я  понял как реализовать получение `s_date`

Comment: Если проблема была только в этом, надо отредактировать вопрос и заголовок, убрав все лишнее.

Comment: Так и сделаю )))